# Suppose $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ and $h:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ are continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ and $h:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ are continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. $g(x)<h(x)$ for all $x\in [-1,1]$. Then there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that $g(x) \leq h(x)-\epsilon$ for all $x\in [-1,1]$?

Comment: Can you explain what you've tried, and what you're having trouble with? For example; what do you know about continuous functions on compact sets? Also, please use a descriptive title - just stating the assumptions in your problem does not describe the question.

Comment: Define $f(x)=h(x)-g(x)$. Try to translate the question in terms of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Note that the function $f(x) = h(x) - g(x)$ is continuous.  Any real-valued, continuous function on a compact domain attains both a maximum and a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

i) $[-1, 1]$ is compact.

ii) $h(x) - g(x) > 0$ for all $x \in [-1, 1]$.

iii) $(0, \infty) \subseteq \cup_{\alpha > 0}(\alpha, \infty)$

4) You should know that the continuous image of a compact set is compact.  If you don't know it it shouldn't be difficult to prove.  (Which means it *is* difficult but ... you should do it anyway; it builds character.)

v) hint number iii is really important